# Using batch file to run a jar file

Tags: java, jar, batch-file

I found a way to set the classpath for the resource file. I am using a batch file to run my JAR. I have set the path like this

```
echo off
cd..
set BASEDIR=E:\SampleSourceCode
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp %BASEDIR%\lib\*;%BASEDIR%\data\;%BASEDIR%\resources\  com.example.main.Main
```

But now when I do any changes to the contents of the resource folder (properties file), the GUI does not recognize the database from the data folder. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking:

Q: If I change the contents of an external properties file, will a running Java process automatically update the property files originally read from the file?

A: No, it won't.

The general solution is:

1. Modify the property in your program
2. Have your program re-write the external properties file

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paulsm4. But as I said, if I make changes to the external properties file. It does reflect on my GUI, but now the GUI isn't recognizing the other files. Have I missed out anything in the script? or is there any command for a batch file to recognize updates in the external file and update the JAR?

Comment: If you're in a development environment, and you need to update a .jar in response to an external file change, then you want "ant":  http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Answer (score 0):

the best way to set a library to execute a .jar file that requires outside resources, is simple use the following batch file:

```
    javaw -Djava.library.path=<path to library> -jar <name>.jar
```

in this way, anything that you change will still be accepted as long as it occurs in your path to library.(or in the jar itself.)